# What sort of tamarisk tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees, evergreens, desert

Is this a tamarisk (≟salt-cedar) tree? It's about 50 feet tall. If so, what subspecies of *Tamarix* is this tree, found in the Sonora Desert in the U.S. southwest?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athel (Tamarix aphylla) is the only tamarisk that size.